# Getting the HTTP status code for a failed to load web worker

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

How can I obtain the HTTP status code returned by the server when a web worker is loaded. I need to differentiate between 404s, 5xx or other error conditions.  I looked at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) and the [Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html) but couldn't find anything. The [onerror](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#handler-workerglobalscope-onerror) event does not carry such information. Getting the reason why a web worker failed to load seems very natural to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not exposed at the moment. You could fetch the worker independently using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()` and then create it from a blob URL or some such.